# Order by statement - two columns

Tags: sql, sql-server, select, null, sql-order-by

I have a SQL select query from table x. In this query, I get `BpName` from table x and `BpName2` from scalar function. I want to order by `BpName2` if `BpName` is `null` and by `BpName` if is not `null`. Is it possible?

Example:

These are my rows:

```
Id    BpName     BpName2
------------------------
 1    NULL       'C'
 2    'A'        NULL
 3    NULL       'B'
```

I want to order them like this:

```
Id    BpName     BpName2
------------------------
 2    'A'        NULL
 3    NULL       'B'
 1    NULL       'C'
```

Comment: Wouldn't this just be `ORDER BY ISNULL(BPName,BPName2)`...?

Comment: what about case when both columns are NULL?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You could order by the `coalesce`d result of the columns:

```sql
SELECT   *
FROM     mytable
ORDER BY COALESCE(BpName, BpName2)
```